# Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more

Tags: discussion, low-quality

I'm not good at being synthetic.

This tool for checking the low quality is indeed really a great tool. When it went out there was no notice of a possible ban. I was critic about that and I'm happy that a warning message was added.

I love this community, I love the enthusiasm of his members. But sometime it's really hard to force someone to do what we think is the best.

The community has already changed his mind and added a warning message. I love it. But I've seen it appearing after just a few questions which are even not so terrible.

On other sites trolls get banned. Here it's more strict and I like it. But.. which is the best threshold? It's very nice to warn people, and I don't know if I'm really near to a ban. But if I'm I wonder if this is the best one.

I don't expect a changement, I want only to signal that it seems excessive to be banned with a few questions some of which also got answered.
People like [Dale Carnegie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Win_Friends_and_Influence_People) clarified that it's not so easy to force people to do what we want by cohercitive methods. The reactions we get is often really different from what we expect. Also, something which works may not work when lead to an excess (the example may look weird, but think to Anorexia. Getting slimmer is effective to get some objective at the beginning, but when it comes to an extreme stuff changes and other problems get more important.)

Is it really needed to be so harsh to ban users for 2 downvoted questions and few more? Has it been checked that it's leading to what the community wants?

Thanks for listening to me.

[image]

Comment: @Sathya: Thanks for putting in evidence the point. But if people will not receive the message in this way I would appreciate if you would allow me to edit back the question-

Comment: @Santhya: but I would appreciate even more if you would open a brief private chat with me or consider if I really deserve this message. It would mean a lot for me in this moment.

Comment: Questions with a score of -1 or 0 are not "medium quality".

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: :( so in your mind it means that I deserve to be blocked. Ok I understand. To me it seems extreme and totally counterintuitive that I risk to be blocked for a question which gets 0 votes. To me it seems very harsh to block someone for this reason (a few questions without answers and votes!!!!!!!). But to you it doesn't seem. I understand your point of view but I'm strongly critic toward it. Thank for answering, I would like you to really put your point of view into discussion (which means to try to criticize it by yourself) and only after see if you really still see it as good

Comment: @Sathya, OliverSalzburg: I think one good possible solution would be to make the filter less harsh for people which have already a good rep on other SE sites. I can easily understand the opposite reasoning: "no! people MUST write beautiful questions" but this reasoning should not be superficial. If I would have 20 questions with score -1 we would not being speaking now". This example is really effective to show why a reasoning like: "people should write beautiful questions" is saying all and nothing.. can you both understand my concernement?

Comment: I don't necessarily think that you need to be blocked from asking. But a question should collect at least one upvote to be considered a good question IMHO.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: yes, I agree completely.. thanks for answering. But the filter settings seems to me too harsh.. Come on. I've wrote for years on this community. And this filter is threating me like a troll. Sometime I open question and answer by myself. Do you think this filter is well accepted by the community? The real community is not only the few dozen of high rep or moderators..

Comment: What's all the fuss about it? Can't you just get over it, create a new account and start asking **good** questions from now on? Its not like someone took away your driving license or kicked you out of school. Its just a website and nothing more than that, its also free to register, btw... Rules are not ideal, but rather a good approximation that works well for majority of average cases. All you are trying to do here is to prove that you are very special. Maybe you are, but then you just have to get used to it.

Comment: Why create a new account @smc? It's a warning. Adjust, and they should be good to go.

Comment: @Bart, you are absolutely correct. My apologies - I did not get the details correctly from the first read. Even better - OP doesn't need to create a new account, which is always an option, btw )) So even less reason for starting a drama.

Comment: @smc creating a new account to circumvent/avoid a potential ban is a good way to end up with all your accounts suspended for a long time. It's much better to just focus on asking better questions.

Comment: @Bart: for me it's kind of hard to answer to your question.. to me it sounds like an historical fact. When the queen Elizabeth was told by people: "we don't have the bread" and she answered: "eat brioches"... If you don't make an effort to understand my concernment is really hard for me to help you to understand it. Have you looked to the horrible questions for which I deserve to be banned like a troll?

Comment: I'm pretty certain Queen Elizabeth [has never been accused of saying that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_them_eat_cake). Your 'Historical Fact" Appears to be a misattribution of a misattribution.

Comment: I have looked at those just now. And I absolutely understand why you have been warned. Nothing terrible happened its just a warning, make your conclusions and move on. Instead of trying to prove everyone that you are very special and need special care, you can just try to understand that maybe everyone else is not like you and this website works just fine for majority.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: thanks for the fix, but the meaning really doesn't change.

Comment: @smc: I'm not asking for a special treatment for me. I'm saying: "have you REALLY wondered on why you think this setting for the filter is ok?". It's very harsh.. that's what I'm trying to say.. Some time ago I tried to suggest to add a warning before banning people from making questions. I got very similar answer to the one you are providing me now.. and what happened? I was right. The point for me is that I love the warning, but I hate a possible suspension with that questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you might be missing the point of Stack Exchange for a little bit there, so let me refresh your memory.

**The goal of Stack Exchange is to create a high quality repository of knowledge and information on a focused topic**.

To achieve that, Stack Exchange erected over a hundred Q&A sites which all operate similarly.

Users posting low quality content **are a hindrance**, they *actively* damage the community, little by little.

Not very long ago, there was no warning. One day, you'd be BANNED, and it would be very near impossible to break. Today, the system is much more forgiving in both algorithm, and in giving you heads up before you get thrown into the abyss.

Questions that just get answered are not necessarily good ones. Our measurement for the quality of any post is the amount of upvotes it gets, however inaccurate it is. Several 0 ranked question + 2 -1 ranked questions (one of which is deleted), is indication that your posts need improvement.

So yes, we expect you to try harder with your questions, or the system will remove you to maintain the overall level of question quality on the site.

Comment: I was one of the guys which started this battle against the lack of warning before ban. I got answers like: "SE is harsh but it's like that" and now that this community had fixed the first step I'm trying to communicate another problem. The filter settings seems to be too harsh.. Come on. I've wrote for years on this community. And this filter is threating me like a troll. Sometime I open question and answer by myself. Do you think this filter is well accepted by the community? Open a survey! The REAL community is not only the few dozen of high rep or moderators.

Comment: @Revious you're behaving as if the system has a personal grudge against you. It flagged you as a potential problematic poster, it had the courtesy of warning you about it, I don't think the algo is too harsh because I can still see low quality content around. Just take it as a constructive note, and shape up. No need to complain about it just because you got the warning...

Comment: This community never admits his errors and hides itself behind sentence like: "The goal of Stack Exchange is to create a high quality repository of knowledge and information on a focused topic" . But actually the lack of warning was only due to an effort in the implementation of the warning itself.

Comment: Now you're making up claims you clearly have no base for (and I kind of do, so please stop). Implementing a warning is simple, and yet it wasn't there for almost a year. No, the reason was that the original thought was that users who ever reach the threshold are not wanted. This approach was changed over time, and now we display a warning.

Comment: if a system would really prevent every low level contribute it would have a cost. Probably the persons would get easily fed up with using it. And the community would not go far away. People are not payed to write questions here. So, coming back to reality, I'm just telling to high rep users that I met a problems with the system. As I told you when the lack of the warning message was another problem. As that problem was solved, I hope someone will take this complain into a serious consideration and will wonder on it objectively.

Comment: I'm glad that the approach changed over time. So you work for StackExchange? You could clarify your intent, we discussed a lot on that problem and no one said: "we don't put a warning since we don't want users which reach that treshold". PS: you changed your idea at the end.. maybe by listening to users, maybe by realizing the problem. I hope you will continue on that.

Comment: I don't work for [se], no. But I am active on various communities, including [metase] and [anime.se] where I mod. I was here when the decisions were made, and were a part of the meta posts that inspired most of those changes.

Comment: so would you like to listen to my concernement and then evaluate and take your decision after seeing also my point of view?

Comment: I honestly don't mind, but your meta post is very aggressive and moody. Try to rephrase it to better reflect your point of view, with attacking the tools that Stack Exchange worked very hard for, in favor of the community as a whole.

Comment: @MadaraUchina: I will try but I'm very bad on it.. I've a good psycholocal knowledge and I would like people to make the same effort that I do. I read many books of personal growth. I mean.. maybe I should have wrote more politely, but people stop to listen and even to think when we become aggressive. I'm really sad on this point..

Comment: @MadaraUchina: done..

Comment: @MadaraUchina: rewriting in a not aggressive way didn't helped.. I only got aggressive, unexplained, downvote as exchange..

Answer (score 2):

So, per your screenshots, you've asked 7 questions. None have been upvoted. Two have been downvoted. One has been deleted.

Do you even *need* a warning to tell you that you are kinda leaning in the wrong direction here? Well, apparently you do - so, you got one. You're welcome!

I haven't reviewed any of your actual questions or even opened your profile; you didn't ask for that, so I'm going entirely off of the information you've provided here.

If you would *like* us to review individual questions and offer feedback on how they might be improved, feel free to ask here - just tag your question [support](/questions/tagged/support) [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) and be open to constructive criticism.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your advice. But I was pointing out another point: I'm happy to receive that warning, and I know how to improve the quality of my questions (here.. on CogSci instead  I've asked for help). I always review my questions now, when I think it can be useful, but it cost time and this community is aware that I'm not payed for making my content perfects. I have to choose on what to invest my time. You, as community manager, would probably like to have better content but also not demotivated users. I think the warning is a really good stuff, but you know what was my reaction?

Comment: On Programmers I have this message from a few of months and I avoided posting other questions. I simply posted on meta the question: "can I open this question?" or I tried to formulate the question to post in code review. What is the result? I got a lot of reputation on CodeReview and I stopped posting on Programming. What I mean is.. we don't always get what we think.. the easy way often doesn't work. And as people can make mistake many people can as well. So the question is.. telling someone that his direction is not the best is ok. But is it working as we expect?

Comment: If you read this comment you can also see an error which was made by this community some time ago: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8741/wait-some-of-your-past-questions-have-not-been-well-received-and-youre-in-dan/8743#comment22521_8742 I said (also to you) that it was an error not even to warn people and I got answered generic sentence like: "if we have two ears and one mouth there is a reason". And then.. I dropped the topic and community changed his mind, admitted the "error" done before.

Comment: I am not paid either; but every answer and every question I submit; is the absolute best I can make it. If you can't do the same perhaps you shouldn't contribute.  It's not a great deal to ask.  Your excuse sounds like you know your content should be better but you don't care to improve it and just want to complain about how if you continue to post low quality content you won't be able to